# Help with Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to solve part a) of the following question:

[image]

This is what I have done:

[image]

Is the above sufficient to prove this part of the question and is it correct?

Comment: Please use mathjax rather than images. This [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good start.

Comment: Where is the induction ?

Answer (score 1):

No, not even close. For one you are proving a statement that has nothing to do with limits, and you are bringing limits into it. Second, your proof is not a proof by induction (as the instructions of the task demand). Finally, you make a false statement in the proof. You say

> Let $A\geq 0$. Then $\lim_{t\to\infty} B^t=B$

The two statements you wrote are completely unconnected, and, more importantly, the second one is **false**. Take, for example, $B=[\frac12]$, the $1\times 1$ matrix with one value, $\frac12$. Then you can clearly see that $$\lim_{t\to\infty} B^t=[0]\neq B$$ which means your statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

To prove something by induction, you need :

- to check that it is true at the first step.

You know by hypothesis that $A \geq O$, then we have (obviously)
$A^{1} \geq O$

so the first step is ok (if $t$ starts at $1$).

- Assuming that $A^{t} \geq O$,  you need to prove that $A^{t+1} \geq O$.

Hence, you'll have shown that for all $t \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$, $A^{t} \geq O$.